# Brownian motion. Solve stoc. integral by using Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

I want to show that following statement is true by using Ito's lemma to solve stochastic integrals:[image]

I define the functions in Ito's model: a(*)=0, b(*)= (2wt-2)^2. f(t)=Integrate[(2wt-2)^2]

Then df=(b^2/2)*(d^2/dwt^2)+(b*df/dst). But it doesn’t add up. How do I show it by using Ito's lemma?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to write formulas in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ito's formula for $(2W_t+1)^3$, and then integrate. More specifically, note that
\begin{align*}
d\left( (2W_t+1)^3 \right) &= 6(2W_t+1)^2 dW_t + 12 (2W_t+1) dt,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
(2W_T+1)^3 - 1 = \int_0^T 6(2W_t+1)^2 dW_t + 12 \int_0^T (2W_t+1) dt.
\end{align*}
The remaining is obvious.

Comment: Can you specify a bit more?